# collectAsState not receiving changes from repository

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I've finished most of the Android Basics with Compose course, just need to do Work Manager and Views, but I've finished the Room sections and have tried to apply it to my first app which is a silly random pep talk generator.

I've got everything working to generate a new talk each time the app is opened, but I am unable to get my button work to allow the user to generate a new talk. I'm also sure a lot of this can be optimized and will appreciate feedback on that, but I'm focused on basic functionality for now.

Here is the part of the Dao

```
@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'greeting' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
fun getGreeting(): Flow<String?>

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'first' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
fun getFirst(): Flow<String?>

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'second' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
fun getSecond(): Flow<String?>

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'ending' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
fun getEnding(): Flow<String?>`
```

Then in the repository (I'm sure this can be improved)

```
fun getNewTalk(): Flow<String> {
    val greeting: Flow<String?> = phraseDao.getGreeting()

    val first: Flow<String?> = phraseDao.getFirst()

    val second: Flow<String?> = phraseDao.getSecond()

    val ending: Flow<String?> = phraseDao.getEnding()

    val firstHalf = greeting.combine(first) { greeting, first ->
        "$greeting $first"
    }

    val secondHalf = second.combine(ending) { second, ending ->
        "$second $ending"
    }

    val currentTalk = firstHalf.combine(secondHalf) {firstHalf, secondHalf->
        "$firstHalf $secondHalf"
    }

    return currentTalk
}
```

And the viewmodel

```
class PepTalkScreenViewModel (
        private val pepTalkRepository: PepTalkRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

    val currentTalk = pepTalkRepository.getNewTalk()

    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as PepTalkApplication)
                val pepTalkRepository = application.pepTalkRepository
                PepTalkScreenViewModel(pepTalkRepository = pepTalkRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the main screen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PepTalkScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val pepTalkViewModel: PepTalkScreenViewModel = viewModel(factory = PepTalkScreenViewModel.Factory)
    val pepTalk by pepTalkViewModel.currentTalk.collectAsState(initial = "")
    //I've also tried collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = "") but no change in behavior

    Scaffold (
        .....
        PepTalkCard(pepTalk = pepTalk)
        .....
       bottomBar = { BottomAppBar(pepTalk = pepTalk)}
```

In the scaffold is a call to a function for a card composable

```
@Composable
fun PepTalkCard(
    pepTalk: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Text(
            text = pepTalk,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium,
            modifier = Modifier
        )
    }
}
```

The scaffold also calls a bottom app bar with a button for generating a new talk and a button for sharing, and this is where my problem is. I've tried a headache inducing number of things in the OnClick section to get it to query the DAO again and cannot figure out what I'm missing.

```
@Composable
fun BottomAppBar (
    pepTalk: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val pepTalkViewModel: PepTalkScreenViewModel = viewModel(factory = PepTalkScreenViewModel.Factory)
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        //region New Button
        Button(onClick = {
            pepTalkViewModel.currentTalk
        }) {
```

I'd think calling the variable currentTalk would refresh the words since it is equal to the function in the repository. I've tried doing mutable state stuff, and live data, and something always complains about not matching the right type like StateFlow to Flow and it feels like this shouldn't be that complicated of a thing to do. I've been googling this for a few days now and it's a little frustrating how many ways there are to do this and how it seems like best practice has changed over time, especially with compose.

Any help or guidance in a good direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to get your DAO flows to requery is to do something that modifies the database. I'm not sure if even that's enough. It might be optimized to only requery the ones that it can deduce might be affected by a certain database change.

So, if you need to requery on demand, I think you need to change these to suspend functions, and create a repo function that causes the flow to requery. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'greeting' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getGreeting(): String?

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'first' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getFirst(): String?

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'second' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getSecond(): String?

@Query("SELECT saying from phrases WHERE type = 'ending' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getEnding(): String?
```

```
// In repository:
private val requeryTrigger = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(
        replay = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )

fun requestNewTalkUpdate() {
    requeryTrigger.tryEmit(Unit)
}

val newTalk: Flow<String> = requeryTrigger.map {
    val greeting = phraseDao.getGreeting()
    val first = phraseDao.getFirst()
    val second = phraseDao.getSecond()
    val ending = phraseDao.getEnding()
    "$greeting $first $second $ending"
}
```

---

However, at this point, the design is a little silly. We have to call a function to tell our Flow to emit one new item. We should instead just have a suspend function for requesting an item:

```
suspend fun generateNewTalk(): String {
    val greeting = phraseDao.getGreeting()
    val first = phraseDao.getFirst()
    val second = phraseDao.getSecond()
    val ending = phraseDao.getEnding()
    return "$greeting $first $second $ending"
}
```

Then in the ViewModel, you can create a State (or StateFlow if you like) for holding the values retrieved, and exposing a function for refreshing that you can call from your button:

```
private val _talkState = mutableStateOf("").also {
    refreshTalkState()
}
val talkState: String by _talkState

fun refreshTalkState() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _talkState.value = repo.generateNewTalk()
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't like the MutableState("").also but doing

    private val _talkState = mutableStateOf<String>("")
    val talkState: String by _talkState

Got it working great, thanks!!